# Swift / Spring 'Date components' error

Tags: ios, swift

Here is the line of code that receives the issue code:

```
let components: NSDateComponents = calendar.components(unitFlags, fromDate: earliest, toDate: latest, options: [])
```

Issue code:

```
'components' produces 'Date Components', not the expected contextual result type 'NSDateComponents'
```

Additional code:

```
public func timeAgoSinceDate(date:NSDate, numericDates:Bool) -> String {
let calendar = NSCalendar.current
let unitFlags: NSCalendar.Unit = [NSCalendar.Unit.minute, NSCalendar.Unit.hour, NSCalendar.Unit.day, NSCalendar.Unit.weekOfYear, NSCalendar.Unit.month, NSCalendar.Unit.year, NSCalendar.Unit.second]
let now = NSDate()
let earliest = now.earlierDate(date as Date)
let latest = (earliest == now as Date) ? date : now
let components: NSDateComponents = calendar.components(unitFlags, fromDate: earliest, toDate: latest, options: [])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift 3 introduces a bunch of new *value types* for existing
Foundation class types, such as `Date` for `NSDate`, `Calendar` for
`NSCalendar`. Some of the reasons were

- to provide proper value semantics,
- `let` and `var` instead of mutable and immutable variants,
- more "Swifty" APIs.

The details can be found in

- [SE-0069 Mutability and Foundation Value Types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0069-swift-mutability-for-foundation.md)

You can bridge between the value type and the corresponding `NS` type
(as you did with `date as Date`), and when existing Foundation APIs are
imported into Swift, the types are bridged automatically.

Therefore `NSCalendar.current` returns a `Calendar` instead of
`NSCalendar`, and `calendar.components` returns `DateComponents`
instead of `NSDateComponents`.

Sometimes the Xcode migrator can fix these issues for you. If not,
you have to look up the new types and their methods.

In your case, a Swift 3 port would look like this:

```
func timeAgoSinceDate(date: Date, numericDates: Bool) -> String {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let components: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.minute, .hour, .day, .weekOfYear, .month, .year, .second]
    let now = Date()
    let (earliest, latest) = (now <= date) ? (now, date) : (date, now)
    let dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents(components, from: earliest, to: latest)

    // ...
}
```

Note that `Date` is `Comparable`, therefore you can compare dates
directly as in `now <= date`. This is not possible with `NSDate`
(unless you implement it explicitly).